# Why sed doesn't replace NULL-characters \x0?

Tags: shell, sed

If I want to replace several lines, for example in a file or in STDIN, and I don't know the numbers of the lines that occur in the file or in STDIN, I can turn the whole flow into one line, for example with `tr`, like this:

```
$ printf "%s\n" aaa bbb ccc ddd | tr '\n' '\0' | sed -e 's#bbb\x0ccc\x0ddd#string2\x0string3\x0string4#g' | tr '\0' '\n'

aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

I want to get that conclusion in this case:

```
aaa
string2
string3
string4
```

Note that this is a test example, in the real case I do not know the numbers of the lines in which to make the substitution. I only know the rows that need to be replaced and the rows that need to be replaced.

As far as I can see, `sed` can replace NULL-characters, example:

```
printf "%s\n" aaa bbb ccc ddd | tr '\n' '\0' | sed -e 's#\x0#\n#g'
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

Why doesn't it happen in the first case?

You can try to replace it with a regular expression - `(.*)` instead of `\x0`, but with different input data, it will make the substitution wrong, as in the example below:

```
$printf "%s\n" aaa bbb ccc ddd bbb ddd | tr '\n' '\0' | sed -e 's#bbb\(.*\)ccc\(.*\)ddd#string2\1string3\2string4#g' | tr '\0' '\n'

aaa
string2
string3
ddd
bbb
string4
```

Can you please tell me how to correctly replace multiple lines? Thank you for your help!

Comment: `sed` is written in C. NULs cannot be present inside C strings. So expecting common implementations of `sed` to tolerate NULs inside the pattern buffer except where that specific implementation of `sed` was designed and documented to go out of its way to do so is in and of itself a stretch.

Comment: (though as PSkocik says, `\x0` isn't a complete escape for a NUL at all in the first place, so there's a significant disconnect here)

Comment: Converting all `\n`s to `\0`s as you're doing with `tr '\n' '\0'` turns a valid POSIX text file into an invalid one (by removing the required final `\n`) and so YMMV with what any subsequent text processing tool such as `sed` does given that as input. You never need to do that, though, so if you think you do for some specific application then post a new question about that and we'll help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the `\x` escapes consumes more than just the 1 zero.
Consider that in `\x0c`, both `0` and `c` are valid hexadecimal digits.

The hex escapes work differently depending on language.
E.g., in C they're super greedy (will consume all valid hex digits that they can).
A saner `\x` escape for non-wide strings would consume exactly two digits (so as to fill an 8-bit byte). Sed's version seems to work like that.

Experimentally, replacing `\x0` with `\x00` works:

```
printf "%s\n" aaa bbb ccc ddd | tr '\n' '\0' | sed -e 's#bbb\x00ccc\x00ddd#string2\x00string3\x00string4#g' | tr '\0' '\n'
```